# using each function on multiple child

Tags: javascript, jquery

can we use the each function on multiple child at once?
I have the following code and I want to use each function on both the child in single line.

```
       $('.right .submission:not(:first)').each(function(){
            student += $(this).val()*multiplier;                   
        });
        $('.right .viewed:not(:first)').each(function(){
                student += $(this).val()*multiplier;
        });
```

Comment: `$('.right .submission:not(:first), .right .viewed:not(:first)').each` try this. not sure though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [multiple selector](http://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/)

```
$('.right .submission:not(:first), .right .viewed:not(:first)').each(function () {
    student += $(this).val() * multiplier;
});
```